# Is there a way to get the end value of an animation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a script that animates an element as follows:

```
var item_height = $('#item').height();
$('#item').height(0);

$('#item').animate({ height: item_height });
```

Now suppose the animation needs to be stopped before it is complete:

```
$('#item').stop();
```

How can I get the end value of the animation? (The total height of the element when the animation would have been complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.stop(true,true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) to clear the animation queue and automatically "jump to the end" of the animation (instead of just stopping in its line)

You could also save the value you want later using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
var $item = $('#item'); // rather than query 3 times, just save this
var item_height = $item.height();
$item.data('origHeight', item_height);
$item.height(0);

$item.animate({ height: item_height });

// later
$item.stop(); 
$item.height($item.data('origHeight'));
```

Comment: Hmmm... that's a very good point. I hadn't seen that there were parameters you could pass to `stop()`

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. There was another similar question posted and the answer that helped is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906420/jquery-height-problems-when-using-stop-in-animation-or-slideup-slidedown/1906894#1906894).

Feel free to close this question as a dupe.