# jquery bind live mouseenter

Tags: jquery, bind, live, mouseenter

How to set a `bind` `unbind` in `live mouseenter`.

How to do: In `slideUp` and `slideDown` process, `mouseenter` & `mouseout` invalid. only finished the process,  the `mouseout` & `mouseenter` will active again.

my code in:

http://jsfiddle.net/bTjP5/

EDIT: In my code, if mouseover and mouseout quickly in and out the div block, the js will remember how many times the mouse passed, and then even the mouse should be stoped out of the div blocks, the div.tile will still `slidedown` `sliderup` again and agian until finished all the times the js remember. So I think it should be do a `bind` the `slideUp` and `slideDown` events. Thanks.

thanks.

Comment: could you please adit your question to be more precise about what work and what doesn't and eventually what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems animating `height` in jQuery, particularly when using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) which I you need to prevent subsequent [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)s queueing up more animations. See [jQuery height when using stop() in animation or slideUp/slideDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906420/jquery-height-problems-when-using-stop-in-animation-or-slideup-slidedown) and the css-tricks.com [blog post](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/).

It may be easier to just use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to manipulate the height, as in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jTRkV/)